# Select photo nested form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Class House, which has_many house_photos. I had created a bulk of photos (`@mainentrance`), that users can select as a `house.photo`, using a `radio button`. To do this, I have a nested form with a `form_tag`. I tried to followed this post ([Using a Form_for with an each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903815/using-a-form-for-with-an-each-loop)), but it's not working because I have a nested form.

Here is the code:

```
<%= form_tag new_house_path do |f| %>

<div class="col-md-3 detailsnew">

  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field :title, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12">

  <h3> Main Entrance </h3>

  <%= fields_for :house_photos, @houses.house_photos do |house_photo| %> <!-- nested  form-->

    <%= house_photo.hidden_field :title, :value => "Main Entrance" %><br /> <!-- title house_photo -->

    <% @mainentrance.each do |photo| %> <!-- render all image users can select -->

       <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="<%= photo.attachment %>"><img src="<%=  photo.attachment %>" alt="" style ="margin: auto; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 0px; height: 200px; width: 300px;"/></a>

       <%= fields_for "house_photo[#{photo.id}]", photo do |p| %>

         <%= house_photo.radio_button 'attachment', class: 'form-control', :value => p.attachement %> <!-- radio_button for each photo -->

       <% end %>

    <% end %>

<div class="col-md-12 actions" >
  <%= f.submit "Submit house", :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary", :style => "color:#ffffff" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Basically, I am trying to use the value attachment of the `@mainentrance` for the `house_photo`. 
Using this code I get an error `Undifined method 'attachment' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations...>`

Comment: Instead of positing the solution you found in the original question you really should post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: Okey, but I can't post an answer because I have less than 10 reputation. I am going to answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using a form_for.
This post was very useful [Rails form with multiple nested models causes issues with radio groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577631/rails-form-with-multiple-nested-models-causes-issues-with-radio-groups?rq=1)

Here is the good code:

```
  <%= form_for(@houses) do |f| %>  
    <div class="col-md-3 detailsnew">

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">

      <h3> Main Entrance </h3>

      <%= fields_for :house_photos, @houses.house_photos do |house_photo| %> <!-- nested  form-->

        <%= house_photo.hidden_field :title, :value => "Main Entrance" %><br /> <!-- title house_photo -->

        <% @mainentrance.each do |photo| %> <!-- render all image users can select -->

           <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="<%= photo.attachment %>"><img src="<%=  photo.attachment %>" alt="" style ="margin: auto; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 0px; height: 200px; width: 300px;"/></a>

           <!-- Solution -->

             <%= house_photo.radio_button(:imageurl, photo.attachment) %>

        <% end %>

    <div class="col-md-12 actions" >
      <%= f.submit "Submit house", :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary", :style => "color:#ffffff" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```